# print all branches in tree in object with parent and childs javascript

Tags: javascript, printing, tree, branch

[Right side is node and the left is the childs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTcZm.png)

I've a tree nodes and their childs as above. I need to print all the branches of the tree starting from the rootnode which is 1Search_01.

Would be greatful if someone helps in achieving this in javascript.

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have already tried

Comment: Vote to close. Homework. I think there's a number of this exact question already on here.

Comment: Hi stefu, i have data in multiple records which are linked, i was able to fetch parent and its child, which i have put the screenshot. Now i am looking a way to create branches with the tree object i have..

Comment: function getParent(t,n,e){"clear"==n&&(parent_list=new Array);var r,l,a,s;if(a=cat.doSelect('name="'+t+'"'),null==e&&(parent_list.push(":ROOT: "+t+"<"),l=t),a!=RC_SUCCESS||null==t)return parent_list;for(r=cat.parent.toArray(),r.length>1?parent_list.push(r[0]):system.functions._null(r)||parent_list.push("<"+r[0]+"<"),s=0;s<r.length;s++)getParent(r[s],"abc",s),system.functions._null(r[s+1])||parent_list.push("<<<<"+t+"<"+r[s+1]);return parent_list}

Comment: i've minified the script. i was getting the branches but last branch doesn't print the complete branch for one example.